# Boost.Python and C++ compiled library error while importing to Python 3

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost-python

In Python 3, I am trying to import a shared library compiled in C++. Currently, I have these packages installed on CentOS 7:

- `g++ --version` -> g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
- `conda list anaconda$` -> Anaconda 3 version 5.2.0 with build channel py36_3

A simple file in C++ `greet.cpp` is compiled into a shared library `greet.so` with **Boost.Python**. I followed a video on youtube [Simple Demo of Boost Python of Python calling C++ library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkYV6AEHtx4) but it failed to find `Python.h` for some reasons. I had to changed a few things in `makefile` and eventually I compiled all with no errors. However, when I try to import the shared library `pygreet.so` in Python interpreter as a module: `import pygreet`, I get this error:

```
ImportError: /home/.../cpp/code/pygreet.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleER11PyModuleDefPFvvE
```

I tried to see what this thing is: `nm pygreet.so | less -p "_ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleER11PyModuleDefPFvvE"` and found these line:

```
0000000000008916 W _ZN5boost6python3da simpleefIPFSsvEEEvPKcT_
                 U _ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleER11PyModuleDefPFvvE
```

I am rather a beginner at using shared libraries and I really don't know how to proceed. Below, I am showing the files in case someone can see I missed something important.

Thanks.

---

**greet.cpp**:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>


namespace py = boost::python;


std::string greet() {
    return "hello, world";
}


int square(int number) {
    return number * number;
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pygreet)
{
    // Add regular functions to the module.
    py::def("greet", greet);
    py::def("square", square);
}
```

**makefile**:

```
CXX = g++
PYLIBPATH = $(shell python3-config --exec-prefix)/lib
LDFLAGS = -L$(PYLIBPATH)
LFLAGS = $(shell python3-config --libs) -lboost_python
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
INCLUDES = $(shell python3-config --includes)

SOURCE = greet.cpp
TARGET = pygreet.so
OBJ = $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)

default: $(TARGET)
    @echo $(TARGET) compiled!

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -Wl,-rpath,$(PYLIBPATH) -shared $< -o $@

greet.o: $(SOURCE)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -fpic -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.so *.o

.PHONY: deafult clean
```

---

Edit.

As suggested in comment, I changed the line in `makefile`:

```
PYLIBPATH = $(shell python3-config --exec-prefix)/lib
LDFLAGS = -L$(PYLIBPATH)
LFLAGS = $(shell python3-config --libs) -lboost_python
```

to

```
PYLIBPATH = $(shell python3-config --exec-prefix)
LDFLAGS = $(shell python3-config --ldflags) -lboost_python
```

and then

```
$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -Wl,-rpath,$(PYLIBPATH) -shared $< -o $@
```

to

```
$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-rpath,$(LDFLAGS) -shared $< -o $@
```

but still have the same error.

Comment: Why don't you use `python3-config --ldflags` to get all flags *and* libraries needed for linking?

Comment: Ah. I followed the video I provided link to and failed to realise that I could have checked `--help`. Then, I would know about it. Thanks for pointing this out. I'll check if it runs ok

Comment: Just one question. What do you think I should provide for `-rpath`? The whole string returned by `python3-config --ldflags`?

Comment: If an rpath is needed, it should be included in the flags provided by `--ldflags`.

Comment: It is not provided there. No matter what I use while compiling the shared file, I get have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Boost provides separate libraries for Python 2 and Python 3. If you are using Python 3, you need to link with the Python 3 specific library, otherwise you will get undefined symbol errors at module loading time.

On Ubuntu, the library may be called `libboost_python-py35.so`. I'm pretty sure (but didn't verify) that different minor versions of the boost.python library are upwards compatible, so you may use `libboost_python-py35.so` with Python 3.6.

If such library is not present on your system, chances are your distro doesn't ship it, in which case you need to build boost.python from sources.

Comment: I see. I have installed boost from package manager (`yum install boost-devel`) and it turns out the boost available in Centos7 is only for Python2 :/. Great. Thanks for clarifying this. At least I know where the problem is.

Comment: @Celdor There might be a separate package boost-python3-devel, check it out.

Comment: `sudo yum list available | grep "boost".*"devel"` shows this: `boost-devel.i686 1.53.0-27.el7 base`. I am guessing __27__ refers to Python2.7. There is nothing more than that. As pointed out, I probably have to compile boost from sources.